# Editing a pyinstaller .exe file

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller

So, i have managed to create an executable file in windows, out of a python script using `pyinstaller`. I tried `pyinstaller myscript.py` and the buid and dist folders were created, along with the `.spec` file

However, at a later time, i am making changes to the underlying code. So what i need to do is recompile and my application works again.

But, is there a way in which i can edit the already existing application? Or do i have to always recompile, after making a change ?

Also, what is the purpose of the `.spec` file?

Comment: You are not supposed to be able to edit executable binaries. I don't know what `pyinstaller` actually does but if it's creating a real executable (which probably isn't the case) then reverting it to readable code anywhere near the original code is borderline impossible. If it is actually just a compact Python interpreter with your script hidden somewhere in `.pyc` format then reverting would be possible, but a rather complicated process that is definitively not something you would want to do since you already have the code in editable format.

Answer (score 3):

Spec-file is needed to keep some options for pyinstaller to build your project such as hidden imports, attached data files, the name of output exe-file, etc. It is always created by using pyinstaller first time. Next time if you want to build your changed project use this command specifying the spec-file:

```
$ pyinstaller myscript.spec
```

For more information about spec-files read documentation: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html